# Latex doesn't format paragraphs properly

Tags: spacing, formatting, paragraphs, layout

**This is solved, should I leave this up for the archive or delete it?**

I am writing my thesis and using our unversities template. It is quite ugly, but that is a different topic.

When I am writing some text, and add 1x Enter, nothing happens. If I add 2x Enter, the current line breaks, another blank line is added, and then the following text comes.
The  regular way would be that 2x Enter = line breaks, text starts at next line (without another fully blank line in between).

How do I stop this behaviour?

Since it is accessible via the website, I guess I can share the template.
This is the general style-file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{../style/thesisstyle}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Universal encoding
%\RequirePackage[ansinew]{inputenc}      % Windows encoding
%\RequirePackage[applemac]{inputenc}     % Mac encoding
%\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}       % Linux encoding

\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}     % New german spell checking
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Font
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}       % Line break support in URL
\RequirePackage[htt]{hyphenat}      % hyphenation in texttt
\RequirePackage{siunitx}            % SI-Unit support
\RequirePackage{courier}            % Courier as \ttdefault
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Headings in normal font

\RequirePackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot                   % clear all headings and footers
\ihead{\headmark}
\automark{chapter}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}            % Math
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}           % Include graphics to document
\RequirePackage{subcaption}         % Multiple Pictures next to each other
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}    % More citation styles
\parindent0pt                       % First line starts imediately
\RequirePackage{todonotes}          % Adds notes on marginpar (can lead to warnings!)

                                    % Page layout
%\RequirePackage[top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}


\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}  % place at absolute coordinates on title page

\RequirePackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
urlcolor=blue
]{hyperref}                         % needed for glossaries

\RequirePackage[
nonumberlist,                       % no page numbers
acronym,                            % acronyms
symbols,                            % and symbols
toc
]{glossaries}                       % for glossary, ...

\RequirePackage{pdfpages}           % for 2018 HAW Corporate Design cover page

\RequirePackage{../style/configurationcommands}
\RequirePackage{../style/convenience}

% orphans and widows are typographically bad
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

% give LaTeX the option to insert more space between words
% (when the line-breaks would overflow the hbox otherwise)
%\emergencystretch 1.5em
```

and this is the master file to be compiled:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,            % DIN A4
  DIV=10,             % Schriftgröße und Satzspiegel
  oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
  BCOR=5mm,           % Bindungskorrektur
  parskip=half,       % Halber Abstand zwischen Absätzen
  numbers=noenddot,   % Kein Punkt hinter Kapitelnummern
  bibtotoc,           % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
  listof=totoc        % Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{../style/thesisstyle}

\makeglossaries           % create all glossary entries (remember: run makeglossaries manually)
\loadglsentries{thesisglossaries.tex}  % load acronym, symbol and glossarie entries

\sisetup{locale = DE}     % siunitx locale setup
%\DeclareSIUnit \fps{fps}  % a custom unit (usage: \SI{24}{\fps})

\begin{document}
\input{configuration/configuration}    % load all settings

\hyphenation{Ba-che-lor-the-sis Mas-ter-the-sis}

% Cover page here, no page number
\ICoverPage

% Titlepage is page one even if the number is not shown.
\pagenumbering{roman}
% Title page here
\input{../style/titlepage}

% Abstract page here
\input{../style/abstractpage}

% Table of contents here
\tableofcontents

% List of figures here
\IListOfFigures

% List of tables here
\IListOfTables

% List of accronyms here
\IListOfAccronyms

% List of symbols here
\IListOfSymbols

% Uncomment if list of source code is needed (rarely).
%\lstlistoflistings  % requires package listings, needs to uncommenting of usepackage

% path to the chapters folder is set to find the images used there
\graphicspath{ {./chapters/} }

% Chapters
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{chapters/chapter1}
% Add additional chapters here
\input{chapters/chapter2}
\input{chapters/chapter3}
\input{chapters/chapter4}
%\input{chapters/chapter5}
%\input{chapters/chapter6}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{literature}

% Appendix
\appendix
\input{appendix/example_appendix}

\IGlossary

\Istatement

\end{document}
```

I understand that the `\parindent0pt` stops the paragraph intendation. I do not like it, but okay its the template.
But I do not see any reason why there cant be regular pargraphs anymore?

Is there any setting to disable this? My thesis is unreadable with the current format.

If I create a new document like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\begin{document}


\section{bla}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Now comes the next paragraph!

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

\end{document}
```

The results are: In plain .tex file without any template styles
[image: In plain .tex file without any template styles]

and same text file with the provided template style:
[image: same text file with the provided template style]

New document = it works fine, just as intended. But If copy the same content into my chapter 1 file and compile it, it does not. There are no more style settings then the one I provided, I just cannot find why it doesn't let latex do its control flow anymore and work properly with pargraphs.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe? If I try to make one with the information you currently provided, I end up with a different result.

Comment: To sumarize: You want to remove the vertical white space between paragraphs (parskip) and just start the new paragraph in a new line? What if the old paragraph takes up almost a whole line? Wouldn't this make it hard to spot the new paragraph?

Comment: Well, if the paragraph does take up almost the whole line, I still can manually add an additional line-break.  
The problem by now is, that it is impossible for me to start a sentence on the following line, there is always an entire blank line added

Comment: your documentclass is styling paragraphs with no indentation and vertical space, that is a perfectly common style (it is used on this website for example) although it isn't the latex default. you have requested this via `parskip=half,       % Halber Abstand zwischen Absätzen`  Your description of this as "not working properly" is rather misleading, it is just using the requested paragraph style.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Sveinung sadly this is my first time with latex and I lack the knowledge to understand what you're saying

Comment: OK. If you want to get rid of the blank line, change the line `parskip=half` to `parskip=false`. However, in combination with `parindent=0pt` it will be difficult to see where a new paragraph starts. On the other hand: This type of paragraph markup actually was used by some German typographers  in a period in the nineteen-fifties or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a matter of working or not working, but simply a matter of style choice.

By default LaTeX uses no vertical space before a paragraph but a small horizontal indentation on the first line.

A very common alternative style (used for example on this web site and the default generally in HTML documents) is to mark paragraphs with vertical space and no horizontal indentation.

The KOMA Script option `parskip=half` requests this latter style (with the `half` referring to the amount of vertical space used).